# Signing webservices api calls with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, oauth, vimeo

I'm looking for a nice pattern that woud help me to fully sign my api calls with javascript (here for some example, vimeo) after some oauth connect retrieved authorization identifiers.

Using ruby with omniauth, what I'm looking for would be to retrieve the url that gets called when you do a ModelName.{generateTokenMethod}.request(:get,{url})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. There are a handful of oauth 1.0a libraries for javascript (You could try looking at some node.js code as an example).

The problem with using oauth in client-side javascript is that it will expose your client secret to anyone using your web service.

Anyone who has your client secret can make requests on behalf of your application, and lure users into generating access tokens by masquerading as your application.